# How can I know which MySQL install is started with the PrefPane in the System Preferences?

Tags: macos, mysql

I forgot that I installed several MySQL (or MariaDB) packages on my Mac, such as rpm or source code packages.

You know the Mac's System Preference has a MySQL quick start/stop panel:

[image]

How do I know which MySQL install it is using?

Comment: The PrefPane is "hard wired" to /usr/local/mysql which is a symlink to /usr/local/mysql-<version>-<macos-version>... (usually the Oracle MySQL installer).

Comment: @klanomath This is an answer.

Comment: @klanomath If you get a chance, you should turn your comment into an answer. It seems to have answered the question for the OP and may help others. :)